# Efficiently compare elements in array with coredata table rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Okey. I have an array with songnames. I also have a CoreData database with the some of the same songnames. How do I efficiently check which songs are in both? I really don't want to compare every song in the database with all the elements in the array by using a for loop. I also need to know which element numbers in the songnames array that is in the the CD Array. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: whats so bad about a for-loop?

Comment: @peko Then I have to compare every single core data row with the entire array. This isnt good programming.

Comment: yeah but micro-optimization is..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the two arrays to two different set and then find the intersection. That will give you the common object(songnames in you case) in both the sets.

Example:

```
NSSet *set1 = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two", nil];
NSSet *set2 = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"none", nil];
NSMutableSet *set3 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:set1];
[set3 intersectSet:set2];
```

In your case you can use the method initWithArray.

Comment: Is there any way I could change this so that I can get the element nr in the first array(the bigger array) of the matching elements?

Comment: @Alex - For your first comment: yes, you can do that, call the method intersect on set1 for set2. example:[set1 intersectSet set2]; just remember to allocate set1 as NSMutableSet in this case

Answer (score 2):

If your array of songnames is a standard NSArray, you have no choice but do execute a linear search operation (i.e. a for loop). If you use a different data structure (like a sorted array) you could shorten the execution somewhat by doing a binary-half-search instead of a linear search to find your matches.

Answer (score 1):

NSArray Documentation has sections on [Querying an Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW8) and [Finding Objects in an Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW20).  Just use a combination of `containsObject:` and `'indexOfObject:`  You'll still have to iterate over the songs returned from your database.

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Song1", @"Song2", @"Song3", nil];    

for(id song in myArray) {
    if([fetchResults containsObject:song]) {
        int index = [fetchResults indexOfObject:song];
        // do something with value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this by using intersection. Zahreelay pointed me in the right direction, but I needed to do something different with the code than what his did. Incase someone else might benefit from this solution in the future, I decided to post it.

```
NSMutableArray *playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Walk", @"The Pretender", @"Best Of You", @"Everlong",nil];

NSMutableArray *coredataArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Walk", @"Everlong",nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int tracknum = 0;

for (id obj in spilleliste) {

    if ([stemmeliste  containsObject:obj] ) {

        NSNumber *tracknumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tracknum];

        [array addObject:tracknumber];

    }
    tracknum++;
}

NSLog(@"Array: %@",array);
```

Output:

```
2012-05-11 01:08:20.154 compare[19936:207] Array : (
    0,
    3
)
```